# Com relação a TDD, o correto é Testes de Unidade, Testes Unitários ou Ambos?

Tags: debate, tags

Tenho esta dúvida com relação a `TDD`, vejo que alguns falam `Testes Unitários` outros `Testes de Unidade`. Então pergunto:

1. Qual a diferença entre eles?
2. Existe alguma relação entre estas definições?
3. Com relação a `TDD`, o correto é falar `Testes Unitários` ou `Testes de Unidade`?

Até as `tags` do **StackOverflow** me confundem :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vi sua pergunta e me lembrei de um posto que li há um bom tempo. O problema é de português mesmo, veja a curiosidade neste post do Aniche: [Unidade, integração ou sistema? Qual teste fazer?](http://blog.caelum.com.br/unidade-integracao-ou-sistema-qual-teste-fazer/)

Comment: do meu ponto de vista é uma tag duplicada, talvez seja o caso até de migrar essa pergunta para o Meta

Comment: Obrigado @BrunoCésar  ajudou a esclarecer um pouco minha dúvida.